# Objects are not being persisted while using Hibernate(3.2.5) with PostgreSQL(8.2)

Tags: java, hibernate, postgresql

I am using PostgreSQL(8.2) with Hibernate(3.2.5). Despite of proper annotations when I try to run my snippet at the back end, primary keys are not generated so it ends up with no record being inserted in the table.

I am trying to establish One-To-Many mapping between the tables Classroom (One side) and Student (Many side). Please find my snippet below:

**Classroom** class

```
@Entity
public class Classroom implements Serializable {  
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;  

    @Id  
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)  
    @Column(name="room_id")  
    private Long id;  

    @Column(name="Standard")  
    private String std;  

    @OneToMany(cascade=CascadeType.ALL)  
    @JoinColumn(name="room_id")  
    private Set<Student> students = new HashSet<Student>();  

   // with setters and getters
}
```

**Student** class

```
@Entity  
public class Student implements Serializable {  
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L; 

    @Id  
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)  
    @Column(name="roll_no")  
    private Long id;    

    @Column(name="name")  
    private String name; 

   // with setters and getters
}
```

**Main** class

```
public class Main {

    public static void main(String arr[]){
        EntityManagerFactory emf = Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory("OneTomanyMyDbPU");
        EntityManager em = emf.createEntityManager();

        Set<Student> students = new HashSet<Student>();

        Classroom c = new Classroom();

        Student s1 = new Student();
        Student s2 = new Student();

        s1.setName("abc");
        s2.setName("xyz");

        students.add(s1);
        students.add(s2);

        c.setStd("X");
        c.setStudents(students);

        try {
            EntityTransaction tr = em.getTransaction();

            System.out.println("Classroom b4 persisting...:"+c.getStd());
            em.persist(c);

            tr.commit();
        } catch(Exception e){
        }
    }
}
```

**persistence.xml**

```
<persistence-unit name="OneTomanyMyDbPU" transaction-type="RESOURCE_LOCAL">
    <provider>org.hibernate.ejb.HibernatePersistence</provider>
    <class> model.Classroom</class>
    <class> model.Student</class>
    <properties>
        <property name="hibernate.connection.username" value="postgres"/>
        <property name="hibernate.connection.driver_class" value="org.postgresql.Driver"/>
        <property name="hibernate.connection.password" value="abc123"/>
        <property name="hibernate.connection.url" value="jdbc:postgresql://localhost/mydb"/>
        <property name="hibernate.cache.provider_class" value="org.hibernate.cache.NoCacheProvider"/>
        <property name="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto" value="update"/>
    </properties>
</persistence-unit>
```

What can be the cause? How to persist them?

Comment: Tables are being created properly... but only data is not being inserted...

Comment: Are you getting any error in the logs?

Comment: @ManuPK: I am new to Hibernate and have not turn on logs..

Comment: Just a side note: 8.2 will be de-supported soon (end of this month). You should really consider upgrading.

Answer (score 1):

Your hbm file says ddl to be updated, so you never know if everytime tables are being created, so instead of this :

```
catch(Exception e){

}
```

can you place this :

```
catch(Exception e){
   e.printStackTrace();
}
```

and rerun